# Unexpected behavior with chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, chart.js

I'm using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/), and it's quite handy, but I'm facing an unexpected behavior when I click on `arabic`. The values change correctly, but if I hover over the `bars`, it shows the `english` values, although both of `Pages`, and `views` array have the `arabic` values.

```js
var Pages = [];
var viewers = [];
var keys = [];
var countryvalue = [];
var lang = 'english';

function fillArray(language) {
  if (language == 'english') {
    Pages = ['home', 'about', 'contact'];
    viewers = [5, 2, 3];
  } else if (language == 'arabic') {
    Pages = ['arabic home', 'arabic about', 'arabic contact'];
    viewers = [7, 1, 2];
  }
}

function getPages(lang) {
  Pages = [];
  viewers = [];

  fillArray(lang);

  drawBar();
}

function drawBar() {
  var randomScalingFactor = function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
  };

  var barChartData = {
    labels: Pages,
    datasets: [{
      fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
      highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
      highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      data: viewers
    }]
  }

  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
    responsive: true
  });
}

getPages(lang);

$('.languageSwitcher').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).data('lang') != lang) {
    lang = $(this).data('lang');
    getPages(lang);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="barContainer">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<a class="languageSwitcher" data-lang="english">English</a>

<a class="languageSwitcher" data-lang="arabic">Arabic</a>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vs6nyhwc/) that shows the problem

Comment: *"I solved this by adding these 2 lines of code"* Rather than putting that in the question, the way things work here on SO, you'd leave the question as if you hadn't solved it, and then post an answer to your own question written largely as though you were answering someone else's question (choice of pronouns is up to you). That's not only *okay*, it's *actively encouraged*. The site will make you wait two days before you can accept your own answer, but that's the only restriction on own-answered questions.

Comment: I just don't consider it as a _real_ solution. Just a workaround. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to destroy the existing chart before creating the new one. So something like

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
if (window.myBar)
   window.myBar.destroy();
...
```

You could also do a similar thing by updating the points and calling `update()`, but `destroy()` is easier by far.

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jzq5umfm/

---

*Note : while removing the existing canvas element and adding a new one would also seemingly work (as mentioned in your comment and the previous version of your question), with `responsive: true`, Chart.js cycles through all created instances of the graph to resize them, resulting in a console error for each responsive graph that has been created and removed but not destroyed.*

*For `responsive: false` you won't see console errors but you'd still have references to those unused instances.*

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfectly. I wonder why is this behavior since `canvas` uses _fire and forget_ drawing methodology. Can you provide a link or something explaining this?

Comment: You mean why it needs a destroy()? It has to do mainly with the responsive option. Chart.js attaches a window resize listener in which it loops through all the chart instances, and if they are responsive, resizes them to fit the parent. The relevant comment is here - https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/src/Chart.Core.js#L893. The destroy is in the same file (https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/src/Chart.Core.js#L975) and remove it from the list of instances (among a few other things).